# modularize awk script to mask sensitive data in delimited file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a delimited file in the below format:

text1|12345|email@email.com|01-01-2020|1

Considering all the fields are sensitive data, i had written the following awk command to mask the first field with random data.

```
awk -F'|' -v cmd="strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {cmd | getline a;$1=a;print}' source.dat > source_masked.dat
```

If i want to mask additional fields I add the following.

```
awk -F'|' -v cmd1="strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 5" -v cmd2="strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | fold -w 7" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {cmd | getline a; cmd2 | getline b;$2=b}' source.dat > source_masked.dat
```

How do i scale it if i want to mask 100s of columns with different datatypes?

Basically, i want to take the following from config file:

```
column number, datatype, length
```

and use it in the awk to generate the commands and the replacement script dynamically.

Could you please advice on the same.

I rewrote the same accepted answer on awk as it took a long time to mask larger files using bash.

The code for the same is:

```
function mask(datatype, precision) {
    switch (datatype) {
        case "string":
            command = "strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | fold -w "
            precision
            break
        case "alphaNumeric":
            command = "strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | fold -w "
            precision
            break
        case "number":
            command = "strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:digit:]' | fold -w "
            precision
            break
        default:
            command = "strings /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | fold -w "
            precision
    }
    command | getline v
    return v
}

BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < "properties.conf") > 0) {
        split(line, a, ",")
        col = a[1]
        type = a[2]
        len = a[3]
        masks[col] = type " "
        len
    }
    IFS = "|"
    OFS = "|"
} {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (masks[i] != "") {
            split(masks[i], m, " ")
            $i = mask(m[1], m[2])
        }
    }
    print
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to read the mask configuration file into an array indexed by column number.

Then, read the data file line by line. put each field in a second array. Then, for each element of the mask array, randomize the appropriate data field. When all fields are updated, output the new line and move on to the next line.

Does this have to be done in awk? It might be easier/quicker to do it in native bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare    mask_file=masks.conf
declare    input_file=input.dat
declare    output_file=output.dat

function create_mask() {
# ${1} is type, ${2} is length
  case ${1} in
    string ) ;;
    date   ) ;;
    number ) ;;
    *      ) ;;
  esac
}

while read column type length; do
  masks[${column}]="${type} ${length}"
done < ${mask_file}

IFS='|'
while read -a data; do
  for column in ${!masks[@]}; do
    data[${column}]=$(create_mask ${masks[${column}]})
  done
  echo "${data[*]}"   # Uses IFS as output separator.
done < ${input_file} > ${output_file}
```

I have not included the full contents of the `create_mask()` function, as I do not know what `type`s you plan to support or format you want for each `type`.

Comment: I was of the opinion that iterating through a loop with large files is resource and time intensive. I will test this with high volumes to see if I need to stick with awk or this approach gives acceptable performance. Thanks

Comment: Both solutions have to read each line of the file. The difference between the two solutions is that the awk solution iterates over every column in the data, even the ones that don't need masking, whereas mine only iterates over the fields to be masked.

The big question is: Where is the bottleneck? If most of the time is spent reading the disk, then optimizing the loop makes little difference and both solutions should perform at a similar level. If the disk access is fast, then my solution should be faster, especially if you are only masking some of the fields.

Comment: I agree. But the cost of reading lines 1 by 1 from disk as in the for loop is less efficient than how awk reads the lines in memory. I saw a comparison between a bash for loop and awk scaling, where the awk scaled well in performance with larger set of rows. I do accept your solution as a modular approach to the problem

Comment: I was facing performance issues with the above approach and found the /dev/urandom that i was using caused this issue. So i went with a similar approach to one recommended by @Andrew Vickerts(Thanks to him) using awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in **rand** function instead to generate a random number.

Define an **associative array** with the list of fields that you want to mask.

E.g. here is a sample code that will mask field 1 & 4

```
awk -F\| '
        BEGIN {
                A_mask_field[1]
                A_mask_field[4]
        }
        {
                for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                {
                        if ( i in A_mask_field )
                                $i = sprintf( "%d", rand() * length($i)  * 100000 )
                }
        }
        1
' OFS=\| file
```

Comment: Thanks. The number of columns to be masked is dynamic and possibly in 100s. Which possibly means, I may have to dynamically build the array from a config file.